# Keeping constant line spacing even with descendents

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am trying to create a command to typeset titles in a document. At the moment I made it as simple as possible to help debug possible problems. My code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\fontspec[Scale=2.6]{Verdana}
\noindent Introdução ao Desenvolvimento em Android\par
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

If you typeset this document you will notice this rendering:

[image: rendering]

I would like to keep the space between the two first lines equal to the size of the second/third lines. I know I can force it manually breaking lines and adding a skip, but I really would like to have that done automatically.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** after reading the answers below and querying Internet, my choice was the usage of the fontsize command like this:

```
\fontspec{Verdana}\fontsize{26pt}{28pt}\selectfont
\noindent Introdução ao Desenvolvimento  em Android\par
```

Comment: That can be done by inserting `\strut`s in your text, though it's unusual to have uneven line spacing like this.

Comment: Why not `\fontspec{Verdana}\Huge`?

Comment: You are specifying that the font should be set 2.6 times bigger than its requested size, but still aligned on the standard baseline, this is not achievable so tex can not maintain the baseline. You want a _size command_ like `\large` not an internal adjustment of the font loading which is desoigned for small adjustments of fonts eg to make x-heights match.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How should I do upscaling properly without the `Scale` option? Could you please have a look at my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557312/135685

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `\fontspec` in the middle of a document and just use the standard font size changing commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{TeX Gyre Heros} % I don't have Verdana

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
\centering\Huge\titlefont Introdução ao Desenvolvimento em Android
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a precise font size, instead of `\Huge` use

```
\fontsize{26}{36}\selectfont
```

where the second argument is the baselineskip in points. You can adjust the parameter to suit.

Comment: Yes, not declaring in the top the font just because I am doing tests.

Comment: And Yes, I would love to use the LaTeX font size commands, but I am trying to mimic a Word document from a publisher, and I need to keep their font sizes.

Comment: @Alberto Use `\fontsize{26}{40}\selectfont` then, where 40 defines the baseline skip; `Scale` should be used only for small adjustments.

Comment: Just done that :-) See my edit above. Thanks

Comment: @egreg You claim that `Scale` shouldn't be used for big adjustments. Could you help me and tell then how should I do it for the whole document? See my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557312/135685

Comment: @Kazibácsi You *can* use a global `Scale` when loading the font.

Answer (score 3):

Use the  `setspace` package and stretch the interline skip to 2.6 too. I took the opportunity to add `\raggedright` switch, to have a correct horizontal spacing:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{8cm}\setstretch{2.6}
  \fontspec[Scale=2.6]{Verdana}\raggedright
  \noindent Introdução ao Desenvolvimento em Android\par
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]