# Scaling font size in the whole document without the scale option

Tags: luatex, fontspec, fontsize, babel, scaling

I have some trouble with uneven line spacing due to scaling. Multiple users pointed out in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251110/135685) that this is due to the inappropriate use of the `Scale` option in `fontspec`. A [proposed solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374549/135685) is to use `\fontsize` instead, but that seems to be a local command.

My current settings are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel} 
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Script=Hebrew,Language=Default,Scale=2]{SBL Hebrew}
```

Hebrew fonts with vowels require significant upscaling, so the options of the `documentclass` are not enough. How do I achieve a correct scaling (i.e. even line spacing despite ascenders and descenders) for the whole document in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Anyway `\babelfont` is just a higher-level interface for `fontspec`.

Comment: @JavierBezos I suppose it's quite clear: If I'm not supposed to use `Scale`, how shall I upscale my font?

Comment: Then the answer is simple: `\babelfont` can do nothing at this regard that doesn't do `fontspec`.

Comment: @JavierBezos I perfectly understand that `babel` just invokes `fontspec`. But as the `1xpt` option of the `documentclass` is not suitable, what shall I do? Shall I use `SizeFeatures`? Will it have a proper `baselineskip` so my line spacing would be even?

Comment: Please provide some *basic but essential* information about your current document setup, such as the document class you employ and the document class options you set, the options you set while loading `fontspec`, the font you employ, and -- last but not least -- the intended amount of scaling.

Comment: @Mico Please see edit.